# ABAP: String Operations: How can I replace a closing tag with its corresponding opening tag?

Tags: string, logic, abap

To make things clearer and easier, I have a method which has 1 changing parameter. The imported string contains text and text formatting options, the method should recognize the closing tags (always `</>`) and change them based on the corresponding opening tags, which can be `<B>`, `<I>`, `<U>`, to become respectively `</B>`, `</I>`, `</U>`.

For example:

- **the input string**:
  `Lorem <I>ipsum dolor sit amet</>, consetetur <B>sadipscing elitr</>, sed <U>diam</> nonumy eirmod tempor <B><I><U>invidunt</></></> ut labore et  <B>dolore</> magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.`
- **should become**:
  `Lorem <I>ipsum dolor sit amet</I>, consetetur <B>sadipscing elitr</B>, sed <U>diam</U> nonumy eirmod tempor <B><I><U>invidunt</U></I></B> ut labore et  <B>dolore</B> magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.`

I tried many manipulations including:

- finding the last occurrence of the opening tag and determine the one that should be used based on the highest offset, and then truncating the string to the offset,
- trying to inverse the string and find the closest opening tag.

Comment: Your question looks like converting SAP ITF format to HTML (ITF is also known as the long text or SAPscript text format). If that's the case, B, I and U would be ITF Character Formats and would not correspond to the HTML old formatting elements <B>, <I> and <U>, so the question should be asked differently, and the answer would imply standard SAP function modules rather than a "simple" text conversion logic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the simpliest/most effective solution, but I have run some tests and it handles also the nested tags properly.

The idea is: we run through the string and keep track of the opening tags in an internal table. The opening tags are like < x> (without the space, x can be any character except '/'). Once we find a closing tag (like </>) this will be replaced (in place) with < /x> (again without the space), where x is the last opening tag (from the internal table).

The method definition:

```
CLASS-METHODS closing_tag IMPORTING iv_html        TYPE string
                          RETURNING VALUE(rv_html) TYPE string.
```

And the implementation:

METHOD closing_tag.

```
DATA tags TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF char01.
DATA position TYPE i VALUE 0.
DATA position_temp TYPE i.

rv_html = iv_html.
WHILE position < strlen( rv_html ) - 1.
  IF rv_html+position(1) = '<'.
    position_temp = position + 2.
    " Check whether it is a html tag like <x>
    IF rv_html+position_temp(1) = '>'.
      SUBTRACT 1 FROM position_temp.
      IF rv_html+position_temp(1) = '/'.
        " Closing tag => retrive last opening tab
        IF tags IS INITIAL.
          " there was no opening tag !
          ADD 3 TO position.
        ELSE.
          DATA(tag) = tags[ lines( tags ) ].
          REPLACE FIRST OCCURRENCE OF '</>'
                  IN rv_html
                  WITH |</| && tag && |>|.
          DELETE tags INDEX lines( tags ).
          ADD 4 TO position.
        ENDIF.
      ELSE.
        " Opening tag => store it
        APPEND rv_html+position_temp(1) TO tags.
        ADD 3 TO position.
      ENDIF.
    ELSE.
      " There was a '<' but no '>' 2 characters after so just move on.
      ADD 1 TO position.
    ENDIF.
  ELSE.
    ADD 1 TO position.
  ENDIF.
ENDWHILE.

  ENDMETHOD.
```

To keep in mind:
My assumption is that every tag is in format of < x>, so one character only in the bracelets. If that is not true (I don't habe much idea about html tags), than the logic has to be modified accordingly.

Comment: As every context-free grammar requires a [pushdown automaton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) to parse properly, this is indeed the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

Not fancy, but it does the job. Might need to tweak the regex in future,  if more than one letter tag names occur.

```
DATA lv_input TYPE string. "your input string
DATA lv_result TYPE string.
DATA lt_match TYPE match_result_tab.
DATA lw_match TYPE match_result.
DATA lv_offset TYPE i.
DATA lt_tag_name TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string.
DATA lv_tag_name TYPE string.

"extract all tag names
FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '<([A-Za-z])>' IN lv_input RESULTS lt_match.
lv_result = lv_input.
"replace unnamed closing tags with placeholder
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '<([//])>' IN lv_result WITH '&'.

LOOP AT lt_match INTO lw_match.
  lv_offset = lw_match-submatches[ 1 ]-offset.
  "assuming tag names are one character long
  lv_tag_name = lv_input+lv_offset(1).
  APPEND lv_tag_name TO lt_tag_name.
ENDLOOP.

LOOP AT lt_tag_name INTO lv_tag_name.
  REPLACE FIRST OCCURRENCE OF '&' IN lv_result WITH |</{ lv_tag_name }>|.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: @SandraRossi: Thanks for calling that out. That was an error on my part. I’ve removed the nonsensical comment.

Comment: & is a valid html character. Also this won‘t be able to handle nested tags, and has high time complexity